# Can't change date format in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a datepicker where it disables all the dates that is stored within the database, and it works just fine. Although i have a problem, the input format that is currently on is mm-dd-yy and my date format in my database is yy-mm-dd which causes problem from my insertion. I tried adding dateFormat: yy-mm-dd and it does not work, i tried placing it outside and inside the function and all it does is making my datepicker not functional. I really need some assistance, thank you! I'm sorry if its a silly question but I'm still new to the jquery stuff. I tried searching everywhere but since i have a beforeShowDay:function(date) function, i cant seem to fix my problem...

Yes i could just change the format of my date column in my database but i have my other guys working on an admin panel application for the website we're connected to one database, but i can't contact them right now. Thank you!

PHP

```
<?php  
$query = " SELECT  * FROM event_table ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$sentToList = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 

  $sentToList[] = $row['event_date'];

   }
$json = json_encode($sentToList);

?>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script >

    var dateToday = new Date(); 
    $(function() {

    var array = <?php print_r($json) ?>

    $('#mydate').datepicker({

        beforeShowDay: function(date){


            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]

        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could use unix timestamp internally and only format the date for display. MySql do even have a function, FROM_UNIXTIME, to use when inserting a timestamp. jQuery datepicker do probably also have functions to handle unix timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things to help with here:

---

### Converting your PHP array to JSON

When you get your JSON encoded `'string'` from PHP you then need to parse it as a JSON object using `JSON.parse(*yourJSONString*);`

---

### Date formatting issue

Date format without the leading `'20'` for `year` requires you to use only one `y` in your format string.

```
dateFormat: 'y-mm-dd'
```

---

### Adding the red X's style over disabled dates

The red X's over disabled dates also requires a bit of CSS.

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default:before{
  bottom: 0;
  content: "X";
  height: 4px;
  left: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

---

### Optional extra JQuery UI plugin

You can even use the [tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#forms) plugin to make selectable dates more obvious

---

### Example

```js
$( function() 
{
  //build up your array
  //this is a mock of var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
  var phpArrayString = '["17-09-30","17-09-29", "17-09-28", "17-09-15", "17-09-09"]';
  
  //parse your json here
  var array = JSON.parse(phpArrayString);

  //include dateFormat AND beforeShowDay options
  $( "#mydate" ).datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: 'y-mm-dd',
      beforeShowDay: function(date)
      {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('y-mm-dd', date);
        
        //You can even use tooltips to make dates you can select more obvious
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1, 'highlight', 'You may select this date' ];
      }
  });
  
    //Optionally - call the tooltip plugin on dates that can be selected
  $('#mydate .highlight a').tooltip();
});
```

```css
/*
  Add this to your stylesheet to include the red X's
*/
.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default:before{
  bottom: 0;
  content: "X";
  height: 4px;
  left: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 4px;
  color: #FF0000;
}

/*
  Simple utility classes for example styling
*/
.bordered{
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.padded{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bordered">
  <div class="padded">
    <label for="mydate"> Date </label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="mydate" size="30" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering 

I've already included that that and it works but my functions for disabling dates does not work already. 
Here's what im talking about:
http://prntscr.com/gl0zh7
Notice that there's an X on the other dates. That function will not work anymore if i included the dateFormat.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to code for me. The output/problem is still the same when i included the dateFormat: 'y-mm-dd'. BUT i found this, http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/1834/ it's from one of the comments in this forum. although the array which i inputted $json = json_encode($sentToList);  is in a double quote format (e.g. ["Array1", "Array2" etc]). while from the variable in the jsfiddle is in a single quote format. Is the quotation the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Oh my bad, I just noticed that it has the same method as yours. Yes, the one you provided helps my "dateformat" problem. All i need to do is to insert the array which i fetch from the database into the (var array) variable. I printed out the arrays from the database which i did with json_encode https://prnt.sc/gl2u95. Is there anyway to make the arrays in a single quote format?. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you again, i just went home from school. I tried the functions you updated, it went back to the problem before which is disabled dates not showing/working, although my date format has been fixed thank you. I'll try to ask a new question about single quote conversion and inserting it into a variable. Thank you so much! It seems that the site is recommending me to move this discussion to chat, unfortunately, i don't have the required reputation. Thank you again!

Comment: Sure no problem. My data type for my dates inside my datebase is "date".

Comment: I added the codes you that you updated and here's is in my console. https://prnt.sc/glfart

Comment: I think the main problem here is that my arrays are in a json string not object. Is there any way to convert my arrays into an object?

Comment: Removed some obsolete comments to make this conversation smaller. Please check my updated example. You need to parse the string as JSON when you get it from PHP.

Comment: Okay everything works now :) i change the line:  var phpArrayString = '["17-09-30","17-09-29", "17-09-28", "17-09-15", "17-09-09"]';" to var phpArrayString = '<?php print_r($json)?>'; to print out the arrays from the data base. Date format and disabling dates from database is fixed now. Thank you so much for lending me your time. It really helps me a lot. One last question do you have good references or links to help me understand more about javascript or query? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the jQueryUI [datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Now if you would check their [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) list,
you will see how can you format your date.

Let us know if you have any further problems.

Comment: I tried

 $('#mydate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

Yes, it works fine. But if i include  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'. The datepicker does not show up anymore. Do you know what's causing this? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you define the format like this?

`$('#mydate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});`

If this is what you've tried already what do you mean with "datepicker not functional", do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes i did that and it works fine without "beforeShowDay: function(date)" function. If i tried including dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' with it and the datepicker does not show up anymore, like the UI does not pop up. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/1834/
What does a log of your array look like and what versions of jquery are you using?